# Fetch a particular string

Tags: c#

I have 7 emails like this:

[image: my email]

Each email has different details but same format (this is an automated email).

I want to fetch the selected (in blue) string.

What I have tried:

```cs
{
    string emailbody = mail.EmailBody;
    String text = emailbody;
    string[] seperator = { "Caller:", "\r\nPriority:" };

    string[] words = text.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
```

`emailbody` in the code has 1 single mail.

Please tell how can I fetch that string.

Thank you.

Comment: If everything is separated by a new line you could use the split function on '\n'  and then look for the entry in the array that starts with Caller. From there you could do another split on the ':' and then take the last entry in the array.

Comment: I think you have mismatch in your separator. the "\r\n" is real text in your body so you should declare it as @"\r\n... or "\\r\\n". And second the Priority is on a newline so you should add "\r\n" also. So in total "\\r\\n\r\nPrio...."

Comment: Just to make it clear the part "\r\n.. is translated into 2 bytes being CARRIAGE RETURN and NEWLINE. See the description for Environment.NewLine.

Comment: Can you edit your question and gives the exact string you would like to evaluate?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var startString = "replication\r\nCaller:wertyui\r\nPriority:"; \\ mail.EmailBody
var startIndex=startString.IndexOf("\r\nCaller:")+2;
var endIndex=startString.IndexOf("\r\nPriority:");
var callerName= startString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex-startIndex);
```

Or it can be use as well this way  (without \r\n) :

```
var startString = @"replication\r\nCaller:wertyui\r\nPriority:";
var startIndex = startString.IndexOf("Caller:")+7;
var endIndex = startString.IndexOf("Priority:");
var callerName = startString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Replace("\\r\\n","");
```

Comment: Your answer is flawed. The string is not "\r\n..." but @"\r\n..."

Comment: .. Unless of course he copy and pasted from the Visual Studio inspector which would translate CR and LF into "\r\n...". But "Priority" is on the next line which would suggest that his "\r\n" are 4 bytes ('\', 'r', '\', 'n')

Comment: We neeed to know the whole code. How the emails  are loaded. But it still can be converted to \r\n.

Comment: Yep, the question needs to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Loads of ways to skin this cat. Here's one that uses split:

```
string lines = emailBody.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string caller = lines.First(x => x.StartsWith("Caller:")).Replace("Caller: ", "");
```

One that uses regex:

```
var r =  new Regex("Caller: (?<c>.*)\r?$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var m = r.Match(emailBody);

string caller = m.Groups["c"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

i wish this code help you :)

```
string text = "your email";
//here by using Split method i'll take all text before "Caller:" in first index of array and all text after this word in second index in the same array.
string[] afterSplit = text.Split("Caller:");
//here i have ignored first index because i want text after "Caller:" also i have removed text which start with index of "\r\n"
string afterSplitAndRemove = afterSplit[1].Remove(afterSplit[1].IndexOf("\r\n"));
```